# Can I create a shell variable accessible everywhere in the system?

Tags: bash, scripts, environment-variables

I am writing a script which requires to store the value of a variable. This value will be used the next time the script is run. First I thought of storing it in a file. Then this crazy idea came into my mind. Can I make a variable in such a way that if I store a value in it, close the terminal and open another one, the value is still there?

Can I make a shell variable fully global, as in accessible everywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "global environment variable space". If you want to make your data *persistent*, then you need to store it in some file. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Path to the persistent storage file
file=~/name.txt

# If the persistent file exists, use its contents as name
if [ -e "$file" ]; then
    name=$(cat "$file")
else
    # Use a default value otherwise
    name="Bob"
fi

echo "Your name was: $name"
echo "What is your name?"
read new_name

# If a new (non-empty) name is given, save it to the file
if [ -n "$new_name" ]; then
    echo "$new_name" > "$file"
fi
```

If you want to make a variable available to every new process, then you can put it in `/etc/environment` (requires root privileges) or `~/.profile`. Once you put it in these variables, you typically have to re-login. Unless it is absolutely necessary, I recommend against this approach. It puts the contents in the memory of *every* (new) process, so it is not suitable for storing passwords or large values.

> Can I make a variable in such a way that if I store a value in it,
>   close the terminal and open another one, the value is still there?

Well, if you only want to expose the values to *interactive shell sessions*, then you can put it in your `~/.bashrc`. Try it, append `echo "Hello $USER"` to the file. It will be executed every time you open a new shell. It will not be executed for graphical logins and such due to a line such as:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

Comment: That was a well explained answer. Thankyou. But one question. My script will be executed just milliseconds after it has been executed before. So will storing to a file be of any problem?

Comment: @daltonfury42 You will run into issues when you have multiple writers. What kind of application are you trying to make? Depending on your task, you might want to rewrite it such that it becomes a long running process. Alternatively, create a single consumer daemon that takes the results from your producer script. Finally, you can try to use a database such as PostgreSQL. You still need to think about concurrency handling, how do you merge changes?